# capistrano is pulling the wrong ruby version from rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I have a rails 5 app.  I was trying to hunt down a memory leak and it opened up a can of worms. One of the worms is rvm and deploy.  I do not have

```
rvm_ruby_string
```

set anywhere in the project.  If I go to the directory of the project, and do either

```
bundle exec ruby --version
```

or

```
ruby --version
```

both result in

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

However, if I do

```
cap staging deploy
```

you can see it somehow picks up the wrong version:

```
DEBUG [778e15cb] Running /usr/bin/env which passenger as deploy@xxxx
DEBUG [778e15cb] Command: /usr/bin/env which passenger
DEBUG [778e15cb]    /usr/bin/passenger
DEBUG [778e15cb] Finished in 0.710 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [0da5c891] Running [ -d ~/.rvm ] as xxx
DEBUG [0da5c891] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
DEBUG [0da5c891] Finished in 0.101 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [f2734c3e] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version as 
xxx
DEBUG [f2734c3e] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version
DEBUG [f2734c3e]    rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, 
Wayne E. 
Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [f2734c3e] Finished in 0.268 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin 
[https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [a2e3d82a] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm current as xx
DEBUG [a2e3d82a] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm current
DEBUG [a2e3d82a]    ruby-2.5.0
```

Now if I simply try to mimic what capistrano says it's doing, by copying and pasting the following to the command line:

```
~/.rvm/bin/rvm current
```

I get

```
ruby-2.3.1
```

So, I'm stumped. Where is Capistrano pulling the rvm var from?

Comment: Enter into your server and check which rubies version are installed in server. Do this in your server `rvm list`. check which version of rvm is set to default.

Comment: Where are you declaring the ruby version you would like to use?
If you are not declaring a ruby version is it using the latest stable ruby version by default. Which is 2.5

Comment: default is set to 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running `cap staging deploy` as a different user then when you ran `ruby --version`.

Based on the capistrano output, you are using `deploy` user to deploy. If this is the case, you need to install ruby 2.3.1 as `deploy` user, and set 2.3.1 to "default and current".

You can test this by running `ruby --version` as both `deploy` user and the other user you used to run it the first time.